# Windows refund for new laptop purchase

Tags: windows, license

I plan to buy a new laptop and I was asking how I can manage the Windows license's refund that I will not use since I already got one with my school.

The computer is a Lenovo's one and comes automatically with Windows. I'm living in France. (I heard laws may change between Europe and USA/Canada for that kind of stuff).
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundling_of_Microsoft_Windows#License_refund_policy):

> OEM policies for refunding unused Windows licenses vary. Some OEMs have programs that specifically allow a user to receive a refund for an unused Windows license. Acer US has a Windows refund program where a user can ship a computer with an unused copy of Windows to the Acer service center and have the computer returned without Windows for a refund. Acer's policy requires the customer to return items at their own expense, and the balance received by the customer can be as low as €30. Other vendors, like Dell, have ad hoc procedures for users to request a refund of a Windows license. [...]  Still other vendors, such as Lenovo, have return policies that do not allow for a partial refund for just the Windows license, requiring the entire computer to be returned to obtain a refund. **Litigation by users denied a partial refund for the unused Windows license has resulted in rulings in France and Italy that bundling Microsoft Windows and then refusing to offer partial refunds for just the Windows license violates applicable law.**

So in France, it should definitely be possible, but the details depend on which company you buy the laptop from. Best ask them before you buy it. [Here's a website](https://wiki.fsfe.org/WindowsTaxRefund/France) that may have useful information.

As for reselling the license yourself: That's probably not possible. According to [this article](http://www.heise.de/ct/artikel/Verdongelt-1766977.html) (in German), the problem is that while it's in theory legal to sell you Windows license, the license key for Windows 8 is secured in the hardware, and while there are tools to read it, doing so may be illegal. Besides, you won't get a full installation medium, only a recovery DVD that can't be used on a different computer.

Comment: You won't be able to sell the OEM licensed assigned to your laptop without selling the laptop itself since its only valid for that OEM.  The license would explain specific transfer rights of course.

Comment: @Ramhound: in many jurisdictions, that kind of license clause is void.